# Linux и NTFS

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Стоит на компе убунта 11,04. Подсоединяю к компу ЖД с НТФС системой. Диск определяется, но списка файлов нет - хотя забит порядком. В чем причина и что делать?

Answer (score 1):

"Многие пользователи, использующие на своих компьютерах одновременно Windows и Linux, сталкиваются с проблемой доступа к разделам NTFS из Linux. Сейчас для решения этой проблемы обычно используют популярный драйвер ntfs3g, работающий в пространстве пользователя через fuse. Однако есть ещё утилита ntfsmount из пакета ntfsprogs, разработанного в рамках проекта linux-ntfs..."
Когда работал с Linux таких проблем у меня не было. Как ручное монтирование так и автоматическое - все работало и все было видно как ntfs так и fat. 
Вот [ссылка](http://www.ylsoftware.com/news/370).

Answer (score 1):

два года пользуюсь убунтой, проблемы при подключении НТФС возникали только со сбойными ЖД. Проверьте ваш диск какой-нить Викторией, на всяк случай..

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего при монтировании произошла ошибка, а глупая убунта не может ничего сказать, поэтому просто ничего не показывает. Сделайте это руками с помощью mount и посмотрите что будет. Иногда ntfs3g говорит, что дескать раздел помечен как "грязный" и поэтому нельзя монтировать.. ну или ещё какая-нибудь причина